# ASP.NET MVC Beta upgrade with ajax form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I got this ajax form in a ASP.NET MVC beta application :

```
    <%using (this.Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Subscriber",
new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onEditResult", HttpMethod = "GET" }))  
            {%>
                   <%=Html.Hidden("idSub", p.Id.ToString())%>
                     <input type="submit" value="Edit"/><% 
             } %>
```

And my controller method :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult Edit(String idSub)
        { (...)
}
```

But the idSub is always null, before upgrading to the beta I swear I see this method working !

I have upgraded the JS files (Microsoft Ajax) and the assemblies as recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my error, it's coming from the spring integration. In the ControllerBase class, the getter for the IValueProvider (the class to get the value from either route data/querystring/form) return the _valueProvider like this :

```
get {
    if (_valueProvider == null && ControllerContext != null) {
         _valueProvider = new DefaultValueProvider(ControllerContext);
    }
    return _valueProvider;
}
```

As my controller are build by the Spring factory from MVCContrib project, it was configured as singleton, so the ValueProvider has a ControllerContext property value from the first request and not the current one.

So this line in the DefaultValueProvider class :

```
HttpRequestBase request = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
```

always returned the first Request object ,which has no QueryString and so no parameter value for my method.

I change the Spring configuration to get a new instance of Controller which I think is a good thing and now the method parameter is correctly populated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this code works (replacing the GET by the POST verb and using the formcollection as the parameter of the controller method)

```
    using (this.Ajax.BeginForm("BeginEdit", "Subscriber", 
new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onEditResult", HttpMethod = "POST" }))  
    {%>
         <%=Html.Hidden("idSub", p.Id.ToString())%>
         <input type="submit" value="Edit"/><% 
    }


 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public JsonResult BeginEdit(FormCollection form)
 {
    String idSub = form["idSub"];
 }
```